# How do you call a procedure given the procedure pointer in Pascal?

Tags: pascal

Given an array of pointers where those pointers are to procedures and where they pass a single pointer passed to a procedure, how do you call the passed pointer?

```
procedure CallPointerProc(Proc : Pointer);
begin
  // ???????????
end;
```

The old DOS method was fairly simple but inline is not available on Windows port so couldn't even convert to ebx,esp, etc..:

```
inline(
    $89/$E3/               {mov bx,sp}
    $36/$FF/$1F/           {call dword ptr ss:[bx]}
    $83/$C4/$04);          {add sp,4}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: This is getting really old. Yet another question today that is sorely missing details that you're expecting us to answer, while you continue flailing around trying to avoid doing the actual work that needs to be done. This is your eighth question in less than two days, all relating to the same, tired old subject - your unwillingness to actually bite the bullet and port your thirty-year old antique project to a modern OS. It would be easier for you to find an old 80386 computer running MSDOS 3.2 and just run your antique program on that antique hardware.

Comment: The question is clear.  There is pointer to a procedure passed as "proc", how do you use that "proc" pointer to actually call the procedure (without having access to inline asm code).

Comment: The question is lacking context, which would be provided if you gave us a [mre] that demonstrated actual code. Three lines of code totally out of context is useless, which you should know by now.

Comment: Is this a function or a procedure? Do they expect any parameters? These questions can be clarified by giving a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you should not pass a blank pointer but a type that describes the exact type of subroutine like parameters with their types and return type in case of a function.

Example on how to declares procedure or function types

```
type
  // A procedure with no parameters
  TProc = procedure;

  // A procedure that expexcts a string
  TStringProc = procedure(str: string);

  // A function that expects and returns a string
  TStringToStringFunc = function(str: string): string;
```

A function that expects a pointer to a procedure and calls it:

```
procedure CallPointerProc(Proc : TProc);
begin
  Proc();
end;
```

A function that expects a blank pointer, casts it to a procedure and then calls that:

```
procedure CallPointerProc(Proc : Pointer);
var
  TypedProc: TProc;
begin
  TypedProc := TProc(Proc);
  TypedProc();
end;
```

---

Demo code that works with both definitions of `CallPointerProc` above. Note that we use the @ symbol to get the address of a defined procedure or function.

```
procedure Demo;
begin
  Writeln('Hello World');
end;

begin
  CallPointerProc(@Demo);
  Readln;
end.
```